# LOAD DATA INFILE from cvs enclosed with double quotes fields

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

So, I got this. Just trying to insert a csv file into a MySQL through PHP PDO driver:

```
<?php
$databasehost = "localhost";
$databasename = "db";
$databasetable = "table";
$socketPath = "/home/mysql/mysql.sock";
$databaseusername="user";
$databasepassword = "pass";
$fieldseparator = ",";
$fieldenclosed = '"';
$lineseparator = "\r\n";
$csvfile = "file.csv";

if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
    die("File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.");
}

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename;unix_socket=$socketPath",
        $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
        array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
}

$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator).", ENCLOSED BY ". $pdo->quote($fieldenclosed)."
    LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator)." IGNORE 1 LINES;");

echo "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records from this csv file.\n";

?>
```

The csv file is something like this(comma separated and enclosed by double quotes).

```
"X410","","4114068500","000010","04/15/2014","04/16/2015"
"X410","","4220521243","000030","04/08/2014","04/08/2015"
"X410","","4130003659","000010","04/02/2014","04/05/2014"
"X410","","4220524277","000010","04/08/2014","04/08/2015"
"X410","","4114038136","000010","04/07/2014","04/07/2015"
"X410","","4130003594","000110","03/14/2014","03/14/2015"
"X410","","4130003675","000010","04/04/2014","04/04/2015"
"X410","","4130003623","000010","03/12/2014","03/12/2015"
"X410","","4130003679","000010","04/09/2014","04/09/2015"
"X410","","4130003679","000020","04/09/2014","04/09/2015"
```

THe `ENCLOSED BY` part is the one that's giving me trouble, I've done my homework and tried `$fieldenclosed = '\"\"'`, `$fieldenclosed = "\"\""`, with and withouth the `$pdo->quote($fieldenclosed)` and any other weird concat stuf I've though of or found out in other topics with similar issues.

MySQL throws this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 2' in /root/csvUpload.php:32
```

Im running MySQL 5.1 in a CentOS 6.4 server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a comma before `ENCLOSED BY`. It should be:

```
$fieldenclosed = '"';
```

Just a single quote -- it's the character that's supposed to be at the beginning and end of the field.

You also mistyped the variable name, didn't end the string and concatenate around calling `$pdo->quote`.

```
$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)." ENCLOSED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldenclosed)."
    LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator)." IGNORE 1 LINES;");
```

Comment: The comma is there, I had a typo with the concatenation while copying the code here (fixed in the original post).

Comment: Coming back for proper closure. You were right on the single double quote part, but, for some reason, in my MySQL 5.1 build, the proper sintaxys was putting the ENCLOSED BY part without a comma before. Weird stuff.